# In python bokeh how to modify the field of a fill_color interactively without js?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to use bokeh to plot the iris data and modify the fill color of the circles interactively but I am running into a problem. I call the plot and the circle with the following:

```py
plot = figure(plot_height=600, plot_width=1000, title="Iris Data",
              x_axis_label = 'Sepal length (cm)',
              y_axis_label = 'Sepal width (cm)',
              tools = "crosshair, pan, reset, save, wheel_zoom")
plot_circle = plot.circle(x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', source=source,
                         line_color=None, fill_color={'field':'petal_width','transform':color_mapper},
                         size='size', fill_alpha = 0.2)
```

which works but when I try to add the interactivity in the call back it is not clear to me how to modify the 'field' parameter in the fill_color argument to circle. I have tried this:

```py
def update_bubble_color(attrname, old, new):
    if new=='petal_width':
        color_mapper.low  = min(flowers['petal_width'])
        color_mapper.high = max(flowers['petal_width'])
        fill_color.field='petal_width'
        return
    if new=='petal_length':
        color_mapper.low  = min(flowers['petal_length'])
        color_mapper.high = max(flowers['petal_length'])
        fill_color.field='petal_length'
        return
select_bubble_color.on_change('value', update_bubble_color)
```

the color mapper limits are handled correctly but the colors are not scaled according to the new choice. When I attempt to change it to petal_length with fill_color.field='petal_length' I get an "'name 'fill_color' is not defined" error.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Full code below for reference

```py
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column

from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LinearColorMapper
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure

# Load Data
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers

# Global constants (even if python dies not like it)
min_bubble_size = 10
max_bubble_size = 90

def get_scaled_size(vector):
    min_vector = min(vector)
    max_vector = max(vector)
    scaling = (max_bubble_size-min_bubble_size)/(max_vector-min_vector)
    scaled_size = [ scaling*(item-min_vector) + min_bubble_size for item in vector]
    return scaled_size

# Color Mapper
color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette='Inferno256',
                                 low = min(flowers['petal_width']),
                                 high = max(flowers['petal_width']) )

# Define source
flowers['size'] = get_scaled_size(flowers['petal_length'])
source = ColumnDataSource(flowers)

# Set up plot
plot = figure(plot_height=600, plot_width=1000, title="Iris Data",
              x_axis_label = 'Sepal length (cm)',
              y_axis_label = 'Sepal width (cm)',
              tools = "crosshair, pan, reset, save, wheel_zoom")
plot_circle = plot.circle(x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', source=source,
                         line_color=None, fill_color={'field':'petal_width','transform':color_mapper},
                         size='size', fill_alpha = 0.2)

# Set up widgets
select_bubble_size = Select(title   ='Bubble size by', value='petal_width',
                            options = ['petal_width','petal_length'],
                            width   = 200)

select_bubble_color = Select(title   ='Bubble color by', value='petal_width',
                            options = ['petal_width', 'petal_length'],
                            width   = 200)

# Colorbar
from bokeh.models import ColorBar
bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper,location=(0,0))
plot.add_layout(bar, 'left')

# Set up callbacks=
    # Bubble size call back
def update_bubble_size(attrname, old, new):
    if new=='petal_width':
        source.data['size'] =  get_scaled_size(flowers['petal_width'])
        return
    if new=='petal_length':
        source.data['size']  = get_scaled_size(flowers['petal_length'])
        return
select_bubble_size.on_change('value', update_bubble_size)

    # bubble color call back
def update_bubble_color(attrname, old, new):
    if new=='petal_width':
        color_mapper.low  = min(flowers['petal_width'])
        color_mapper.high = max(flowers['petal_width'])
        fill_color.field='petal_width'
        return
    if new=='petal_length':
        color_mapper.low  = min(flowers['petal_length'])
        color_mapper.high = max(flowers['petal_length'])
        fill_color.field='petal_length'
        return
select_bubble_color.on_change('value', update_bubble_color)

# Set up layouts and add to document
curdoc().add_root(column(plot, row(select_bubble_size,select_bubble_color), width=800))
curdoc().title = "Iris Data"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fill_color` is a property of the glyph, you will need to access it through the glyph:

```
plot_circle.glyph.fill_color
```

In your script there is not free variable `fill_color` anywhere, which is the source of the `NameError`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Replacing the fill_color line with 'plot_circle.glyph.fill_color['petal_width']' eliminates the error but it does not update the colors in the plot. I tried further adding plot_circle.update() but that did not update the colors with the new scaling either. Hmmm

Comment: Actually the added line was 'plot_circle.glyph.fill_color['field']='petal_width'

Comment: Finally!! The line that did the magic was 'plot_circle.glyph.fill_color={'field':'petal_length','transform':color_mapper}'